# Node.js + MongoDB + Express + Mongoose. How to require all the models in a particular folder by a simple code?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, models

Consider this is my folder structure

```
express_example
|---- app.js    
|---- models    
|-------- songs.js    
|-------- albums.js    
|-------- other.js    
|---- and another files of expressjs
```

my code in file **songs.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
, Schema = mongoose.Schema
, ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var SongSchema = new Schema({
name: {type: String, default: 'songname'}
, link: {type: String, default: './data/train.mp3'}
, date: {type: Date, default: Date.now()}
, position: {type: Number, default: 0}
, weekOnChart: {type: Number, default: 0}
, listend: {type: Number, default: 0}
});

mongoose.model('Song', SongSchema);
```

in file albums.js

```
  var mongoose = require('mongoose')
, Schema = mongoose.Schema
, ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var AlbumSchema = new Schema({
name: {type: String, default: 'songname'}
, thumbnail: {type:String, default: './images/U1.jpg'}
, date: {type: Date, default: Date.now()}
, songs: [SongSchema]
});
mongoose.model('Album', AlbumSchema);
```

I can get any model by:

```
require('mongoose').model(name_of_model);
```

But how to require all the models in a particular folder by a simple code not by name_of_model? 
In above example all models in the folder ./models/*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var models_path = __dirname + '/app/models'
fs.readdirSync(models_path).forEach(function (file) {
  require(models_path+'/'+file)
})
```

Comment: This is exactly (but lot less readable) what I suggested to you when I said use node-require-all.

Comment: don't these (each) need to be assigned to a local variable?

i.e. when requiring something, we usually

     var Users = require('models/users.js');

I really like the solution you provide, I am just running into issues where, without a local declaration (above), I get "users is not defined".

Comment: @mattbontrager: You could try something like `var users = mongoose.model("Users");` But I am not sure how your model is registered. Try this code to register mongoose models. `mongoose.model("Users",Users);` then above code should work. Happy coding!

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni: Thanks. That's always worked fine for me. I was trying to understand if this answer, which is an elegant solution btw, had a way to declare each of the models in the forEach loop (saving multiple lines of code declaring each local var). But thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You have export your model in each of files in "model" folder. For example, do as follows,

```
exports.SongModel = mongoose.model('Song', SongSchema);
```

Then create a common file in model folder with name "index.js" and write following line

```
exports = module.exports = function(includeFile){  
  return require('./'+includeFile);
};
```

Now, Go to your js file where you need "Song" model and add your module as follows,

```
var SongModel = require(<some_parent_directory_path>+'/model')(/*pass file name here as*/ 'songs');
```

For example,
If i write the code to list all songs in songslist.js and file placed in parent directory as follows,

```
|---- models
|-------- songs.js
|-------- albums.js
|-------- other.js
|---- and another files of expressjs
|---- songslist.js
```

Then you can add "songs model" like

```
var SongModel = require('./model')('songs');
```

Note: There are more alternate ways to achieve this.

Comment: Not clearly explained. please mention what is './'+ includeFile and what do you mean by Go to your code file ? All are code files !

Comment: @Amol M Kulkarni: Thanks for your comment. I have modified my post bit more.

Comment: good answer however small typo you need `exports.SongModel` not `export.SongModel`

Answer (score 2):

You might use a module such as [node-require-all](https://github.com/felixge/node-require-all) which allows you to require all files from a specific folder (you can even use filter criteria).

To give you an example (taken from the module's readme file):

```
var controllers = require('require-all')({
  dirname     :  __dirname + '/controllers',
  filter      :  /(.+Controller)\.js$/,
  excludeDirs :  /^\.(git|svn)$/
});

// controllers now is an object with references to all modules matching the filter
// for example:
// { HomeController: function HomeController() {...}, ...}
```

I think that this should fulfill your needs.